# I can't find Terminal Services Manager

Tags: windows-server-2003, windows-terminal-services

I am obviously stupid... because I'm logged into this Windows 2003 Server box as administrator, yet when I go under Administrative Tools, I can't find "Terminal Services Manager".  Terminal Services are installed... I'm using them right now... and I know that's where the manager is supposed to be... yet it is not

what am I missing?  why isn't it showing?  where else can I find it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Who else connects to this box?  In the past where I work some of my coworkers actually moved the Link for the Terminal services Manger when they were attempting to create a shortcut to the console on their desktop or quick-launch.

You should always just be able to run

```
%SystemRoot%\system32\tsadmin.exe directly.
```

Comment: +1, this was freakin' annoying. Coworkers deserve a beat-down for doing this sort of thing!

Comment: +1 to Moose for eluding to a weekly occurrence in my old dept (the beat-down that is)

Comment: Oh yeah, and to Zoredache for the answer :)

Comment: Of course I think Microsoft deserves part of the blame for making it so easy for people to accidentally remove stuff from that location.

Comment: @Zoredache, What's the equivalent of tsadmin.exe on Server 2012?

Comment: @Pacerier not really sure.  I know Microsoft changed many things.  I know some of the management functionality is part of servermanager.

Answer (score 5):

Have your tried `tsadmin` on the command line? If this works, just create a new shortcut...

Comment: u were first, u win!

Comment: sorry... I just found that the link was actually moved by someone else... and that's pretty much exactly what Zoredache said... so he is more technically correct...

Answer (score 0):

More specifically you should see it showing up in the start menu under a folder called "Terminal Services"  that is inside the folder "Administrator Tools"  that is inside the Control Panel list...   that is the normal place you'd find it.

Answer (score -2):

Go to Run and type tscc.msc, then click OK.